# how to use CloudFront or any other CDN with meteor application.

Tags: meteor, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am not getting any good document for using CDN with meteor application. 
Anyone can guide me to CDN with meteor application ?

Thanks,
hare

Answer (score 1):

I've detailed how we accomplished this at Edthena in [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/cdn). The TLDR is:

Add this line somewhere in your server code:

```
WebAppInternals.setBundledJsCssPrefix(CDN_URL);
```

Where `CDN_URL` is your CloudFront URL (e.g. https://a27n0s89ik4xb3.cloudfront.net).

We kept the defaults when creating the CloudFront distribution except for the following:

```
Origin Domain Name: myapp.example.com
Origin ID: myapp.example.com
Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTPS Only
Compress Objects Automatically: yes
```

If you serve your own fonts, you can end up with cross origin errors (unless you use a font data URL). Josh Owens describes how to deal with that in [his post](http://joshowens.me/using-a-cdn-with-your-production-meteor-app/).